# ggplot2: Place factor labels on overlaid histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot 3 overlaying histograms together acording to 3 diffrnet factors in the data (the factors are a,b,c)
now everything is coming out fine the only thing i am having trouble with is putting the name of the factor on the actual graph on the correct histogram.basically what I am trying to do is have the same graph with 'a' on the red histogram ,'b' on the blue histogram and 'c' on the green histogram
anybody knows how to do that?
[image: in the link you can see the graph i have]

Comment: Use `annotate` and position text at x=sapply( xx, mean) and y at 4.

Comment: thanks alot, just one more thing my data is made up from random samples so this means there might be little changes every time i run the code is there a way to position the text in the middle of the histogram without giving a specific number?

Comment: if you tabled the values using the breaks used for the histograms and took 1/2 the max value, that might succeed. Hard to say how difficult that wold be without a minimal working example upon which to experiment. That is _your_ responsibility.